# Send session data: Php on one server and jsp on another

Tags: php, apache, jsp, tomcat, webserver

My php is ran on apache webserver on port 80.
My jsp is ran on apache tomcat on port 8080.

I am trying to get the session variable i set at the php page in my jsp page.

Will this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will not work. Both are completely different. A PHP session cannot be recognized by JSP Script or vice-versa.

Below are some indirect ways to achieve the scenario..

#### Way 1:

An ugly hack would be , write the session variable from PHP page to a file, such that a JSP variable can open the file and read it.

#### Way 2:

Set the session variable through PHP and pass it through the JSP script as a parameter via querystring.

Comment: I passed the parameter via query string from php to a java servlet. The servlet then sets the parameter to a session scope variable

Comment: Yes, can this data be sniffed though? I hope it is secure.